# Django model filter avoid join when filtering by relation id

Tags: sql, django, join, orm

Django ORM query

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(category__id=1111)
```

This generates following sql query, [join used]

```
""""
select * 
FROM "project" 
INNER JOIN "category" ON ( "project"."category_id" = "category"."id" ) 
WHERE "project"."category_id" = 1111
""""
```

Is it possible to avoid join and get result like this?

```
""""
select * 
FROM "project" 
WHERE "project"."category_id" = 1111
""""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying db column is called `category_id` (with a single underscore); you can filter on that directly:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(category_id=1111)
```